# JDBC -- ResultSet values for column functions

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

How to get the outcome of the query-- the AVG(DIST).

MySQL is showing this result under the column "AVG(DIST)"-- no other clue.

How do i read this value from the `ResultSet` instance (`rs` in below code)?

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT AVG(DIST) FROM POOL_TABLE");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

[`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) seems to be referring to them all by column names.

Not well-familiar to JDBC -- yet!

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
double avg = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    avg = rs.getDouble(1);
}
```

Use alias if you have many aggregate functions in your query. See below answer!

Answer (score 6):

You can use an alias name in the query and retrieve the value in any of the two ways.!

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT AVG(DIST) AS AVERAGE_ALIAS FROM POOL_TABLE");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

double avg = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    avg = rs.getDouble(1);
    // OR
    avg= rs.getDouble("AVERAGE_ALIAS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PreparedStatement used for inserting of data,
i think you should use Statement.

```
Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(DIST) FROM POOL_TABLE");
if( rs.next() ){
  System.out.print( rs.getString(1) );
}
```

i hope this example would help you :)

Comment: PreparedStatement is compiled at start-up -- similar to NamedQuery of hibernate. could just be that it can't be used for insertion-- just like Hibernate NamedQuery cant.